# After installing/configuration of magento with docker getting unable to connect

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, magento2

Hello all Connections Greeting,

I am using this repository https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento for magento2 installation with docker.

I installed  magento 2.3.3 and configured php 7.3 in docker file.

Problem is installation is completed without any error but, I am getting unable to connect after every new installation in browser.

Please help if you facing this same issue.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Refer below Image I am getting this page]

[image: This is installation command screen which is completed]

`docker-compose.yml` file

```
# Mark Shust's Docker Configuration for Magento
# (https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento)
#
# Version 34.2.0

version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-4
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8443:443"
    links:
      - db
      - phpfpm
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:7.3-fpm-0
    links:
      - db
    volumes: *appvolumes

  db:
    image: percona:5.7
    command: --max_allowed_packet=64M
    ports:
      - "8080:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine

  elasticsearch:
    image: markoshust/magento-elasticsearch:7.6.2-2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"

  myadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    depends_on:
      - db

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq

  # Disabling cron by default as it uses higher CPU, enable if needed
  #cron:
  #  image: markoshust/magento-php:7.4-fpm-2
  #  user: root
  #  command: /usr/local/bin/cronstart
  #  tty: true
  #  links:
  #    - db
  #  volumes: *appvolumes

volumes:
  appdata:
  dbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
  sockdata:
  ssldata:
```

I am running below commands step by step

1. `git clone https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento.git`
2. `cd docker-magento` & `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markshust/docker-magento/master/lib/template | bash`
3. `bin download 2.3.3` & then add host in host file
4. `bin/setup myhost.com`
5. successfully installed magento database also created success fully but I can not access through browser.

Comment: please share more details, any modification done in docker file or command you are running or exact docker file. Above shared information, inappropriate can not debug the issue based on it.

Comment: have you added a record in DNS or host file for `magento.test2`? i would suggest instead of directly trying with hostname first try with port forwarding output is coming on localhost or not.

Comment: @HarshManvar Yes I have added my host in `/etc/hosts` file. I have done installation two three times in different machine but if once I get some error in installation then after I can not done successfully installation every time I got the scree `unable to connect`

Comment: did you tried other services ?  are they accessible Rabbitmq, Redis. Elasticsearch? please verify external services are not failing ES cluster health indexes & shard are there, redis using redis-cli & RabbitMQ over management console.

Comment: also, did you try with HTTP ? as firefox trying on HTTPS or else directly hot `locahost:8080`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both http, https and with port also. I tried many service but before it was working.

Comment: weirdly it's working for me in chrome on HTTP while on HTTP sit's giving cert error. All service are running rabbimq, ES, Redis and not a single getting crash or exit.

Comment: Yes for me also working before. but when I install and if some error is coming while installing (like database access denied for wrong credential) then it will not run proper second time.